# Use spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure without access key and secret key, but assume role?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, cloud, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

We have a spring cloud function deployed on AWS lambda. How can we get spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure to work without access key and secret key, assuming the keys set by the lambda execution role instead?

If we use the autoconfigure, it always throws:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'tarodb': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load
AWS credentials from any provider in the chain:
[com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@7e990ed7:
Unable to load credentials from service endpoint,
com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@821330f: profile
file cannot be null]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently you need to provide custom credentials provider bean that assumes role in order to prevent Spring Cloud AWS to create the default credentials provider ([this bean specifically](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration.java#L52)

You can take a look how to implement credentials provider that assumes role [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/pull/617). This PR will be merged in Spring Cloud AWS 2.3.